# Count number of lines in text skipping the empty ones

Tags: java

I need help with this. Can you tell me how to calculate the number of lines in the input.txt without counting the empty space lines?

So far, I tried:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    int lines = 0;
    while (reader.readLine() != null)
    lines++;
```

So, this code is able to count the number of lines, but with the empty lines! I know that there are characters /n which illustrates the new line but I do not know how to integrate it in the solution.

I also tried to calculate number of lines, number of empty lines and subtract them, but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
int lines = 0;
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    if(!"".equals(line.trim())){
        lines++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to work but why BufferedReader returns 17 lines when I have only 12? LineNumberReader returns 12.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to remember the line you're looking at, and check it before counting:

```
int lines = 0;
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line.isEmpty()) {
        lines++;
    }
}
```

Note that you should be closing your reader too - either in an explicit `finally` statement, or using a try-with-resources statement in Java 7. I'd advise not using `FileReader`, too - it always uses the platform default encoding, which isn't a good idea, IMO. Use `FileInputStream` with an `InputStreamReader`, and state the encoding explicitly.

You might also want to skip lines which consist entirely of whitespace, but that's an easy change to make to the `if (!line.isEmpty())` condition. For example, you could use:

```
if (!line.trim().isEmpty())
```

instead... although it would be cleaner to find a helper method which just *detected* whether a string only consisted of whitespace rather than constructing a new string. A regex could do this, for example.

Comment: [*isEmpty*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()) returns true if and only if the length is zero - meaning, it counts lines that contains spaces.

Comment: @alfasin: Yes, hence the comment at the end of the answer. The question is slightly unclear on this. I've expanded the answer too.

Comment: A better explanation to the same code I gave when the OP asked this before ;)

Answer (score 2):

[`BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) only returns `null` when the end of the stream has been reached.  To not count empty lines, test if the line exists and if it's empty then don't count it.

Quoting the linked Javadocs above:

> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

Answer (score 1):

Clean and fast.

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader("Your inputStream or FileReader")) {
            nbLignes = (int) reader.lines().filter(line -> !line.isEmpty()).count();
        }
```